# Three term recurrence relation with two indices and variable coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, finite-differences

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. I would like to solve the following non-constant, two-indices recurrence relation on $u = (u_j^n)^{n=1, 2, \dots}_{j=0, 1, \dots}$:
$$
u_j^0 = 0, \qquad \text{for} \quad j \geq 0.
$$
$$
u_0^{1} = 1, \qquad u_{j}^{1} = 0, \quad \text{for} \quad j = 1, 2, \dots,
$$
and for $n = 1, 2, \dots$
$$
u_0^{n+1} = \tfrac{1}{2}(1+c)u_0^{n} -c u_1^{n}, \qquad u_{j}^{n+1} = cu_{j-1}^n - cu_{j+1}^n + u_{j}^{n-1}, \quad \text{for} \quad j = 1, 2, \dots.
$$
Is there any way to find the expression of $u_j^n$ (take for example $c=1/2$ to simplify)?
The straightforward result is that $u_{n-1}^n = c^{n-1}$ and that $u_{n-2}^n = (1+c)c^{n-2}$.

Many thanks!